# change xamarin navigator's animation

Tags: android, navigation, xamarin.forms

I make App with xamarin in VS2015.

I add contentPage with App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync,

and if tap hardware's back key, Navigator working popModalAsync with animation.

how change animation(no animation) if I touch Physical backKey in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure whether or not I fully understand the question but you could simply call `PopModalAsync(false)` which disables the animation. The call without this parameter always uses the animation.

UPDATE:
Each Xamarin Forms page has an override called `OnBackButtonPressed`. You could override this to add your custom behavior. Something like this:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed ()
{
  PopModalAsync(false);
  return true;
}
```

You have to make OnBackButtonPressed return true in order to block the default behavior.

Comment: then, not using PopModalAsync(false), use android phone's back key's popModalAsync is always with animation?

Comment: No problem! Please mark this as the answer if it helped you :)